# вопрос про массив php

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте, я выбираю из бд данные и помещаю их в массив кодом:

```
$u[$i]->u= $this->getRow("SELECT user, unm FROM users WHERE id = ?i", $this->q[$i]['uid']);
```

Можно ли как то в начало массива, куда идут выбранные из бд данные, добавить ключ ['id'] и значение 1 и сделать это в том же месте где одновременно выбираются данные из бд?

То есть что-то на подобии `$u  = ['id'] => 1`+ запрос который я указал в коде выше.

Answer (score 0):

```
$u[$i]->u= array('id'=>1) + $this->getRow("SELECT user, unm FROM users WHERE id = ?i", $this->q[$i]['uid']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Или иначе:

```
$u[$i]->u= $this->getRow("
SELECT
1 as id,
user,
unm
FROM users
WHERE id = ?i", $this->q[$i]['uid']);
```

В этом случае SQL добавит вам поле `id` в результат и сделает его равным 1